# Laravel 4 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I have this script:

```
<script>
    function selectModSetProd(prodId,setId,objControl){

        function ifOK(r){
            objControl.style.background="'"+r.color+"'";
        }

         function ifError(e){
            alert('An error occurred when making the request: '+e.statusText);
        }

        function petition(prodId,setId,objControl){

            var data = {
               prod: prodId,
               set: setId,
            };

            var post = $.post("sql.php", data, ifOK, 'json');
            post.error(ifError);       

        }

       var set = objControl.value;
       if(confirm("Are you sure to start "+set+"?"))

            petition(prodId,setId,objControl);          
    }
</script>
```

In laravel 4, but I have this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined "

Someone could help me with this error please?

Comment: I don't know what laravel is but have you included jQuery somewhere in your page? It seems that $ is undefined, which is the jQuery object. Try also with 'jQuery.post' instead of '$.post'

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is loaded? Your error most likely happens because your `window.$` is undefined.

Comment: yes, because I can see the message for confirm or not, but if i confirm i get this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are most likely getting the post error because your $.post is trying to go to sql.php which is not defined in your laravel routes.

update your script from sql.php to {{url().'/sql'}}

and add a sql route to laravel routes.

That's the simple solution or you can create a more restful approach to handle your ajax routes and controllers. More info on that is located at laravel.com

btw you should always wrap your jquery to make sure it loads like i posted earlier.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your script with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

$.post will not work until angular is loaded.

your code should read:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function selectModSetProd(prodId,setId,objControl){

    function ifOK(r){
        objControl.style.background="'"+r.color+"'";
    }

     function ifError(e){
        alert('An error occurred when making the request: '+e.statusText);
    }

    function petition(prodId,setId,objControl){

        var data = {
           prod: prodId,
           set: setId,
        };

        var post = $.post("sql.php", data, ifOK, 'json');
        post.error(ifError);       

    }

   var set = objControl.value;
   if(confirm("Are you sure to start "+set+"?"))

        petition(prodId,setId,objControl);          
}
});
```

Comment: if I put what you said to me, nothing works, I can not see the message to confirm and I get other errors: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined prodList:132
(anonymous function) prodList:132
Uncaught ReferenceError: selectModSetProd is not defined prodList:91
onchange

Comment: are you linking to jquery library?

Comment: yes, this:     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: if you are using laravel can you test that you can hit sql.php. Usually laravel will not serve sql.php. You would need that as part of your laravel routes.